# MySQL passwordless access via SSH tunnel - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I have a new MySQL 8 server installed. Fresh, clean, straight from the package.
Now I want to connect to it with DBeaver (a GUI tool).
It has a secure feature as SSH tunnel.
The tunnel works. I connect over SSH using my private key.

Then I try to connect as root to localhost with DBeaver (over the tunnel), and that gives me "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" error message.

Why is that?
When I SSH to the server with putty as root, then type mysql - it just works. I have full access.

BTW, I tried to use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" in DBeaver configuration, but it didn't help.

Here's my mysql.user table:

```
mysql> select host, user from user;
+-----------+------------------+
| host      | user             |
+-----------+------------------+
| localhost | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost | mysql.infoschema |
| localhost | mysql.session    |
| localhost | mysql.sys        |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
```

[image]

Any idea how to configure the access? Or maybe I must set a password? But why does it work in terminal?

Comment: Trying to use root for everyday tasks is considered a very bad idea.

Comment: Your are not using Ubuntu? We do not use root. Please create a dedicared user and password for a connection to MySQL and do not compromize on security. Use this as a guideline https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/

Comment: This was not everyday task. I was setting up a new MySQL server, this was supposed to be done once only, then excessive access removed. But of course it's probably a good thing MySQL doesn't allow that. I guess I was too lazy ;) I made it properly and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `root` from outside the server. This is intentional on the part of MySQL because people would (far too often) put up a website with a MySQL backend and bug-riddled front-end, use a simple password, and get pWn3d … often in more ways than one.

A quick way forward is to create another account for all your admin work, then grant all privileges with the grant option. The process would look like this:

```
CREATE USER 'harry'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'harry'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Problem solved